# Codeigniter custom validation problem

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I'm trying to validate a username (connected to the mysql) but my coustom validation (callback) won't work.

Controller
http://pastebin.com/RLitWDYf

Model
http://pastebin.com/6xygLwW5

How come my callback won't give any errors when a username is already in use?

Answer (score 1):

replace `$this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The username %s already exist');` with `$this->form_validation->set_message('username', 'The username %s already exist');` You must set the message for username and not username_check. Also check if you are echoing the error in your view using `<?php echo form_error('username') ?>`

and then move

```
if($this->home_model->check_username($username)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The username %s already exist');
        }
```

to a function on it's own within Home controller

```
function username_check($username) {
if($this->home_model->check_username($username)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The username %s already exist');
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have now replaced the line, as you said. And it's still not working. Yes, i do display the form error. I get everything else, but not the "invalid username" error..

Comment: doh, callback is available only for functions.